# Django - should I use only 1 view for all website?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

Lets say I want to make a website in which only one HTML template is used. For example, if one wants to create a new object, he clicks a button, and form shows up, leaving the remaining web page intact. My question is simples: should I use only 1 view to handle all the possible inputs/outcomes or should I have multiple views that handle the same template?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally speaking, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) code is always best. If you can reuse a single template and it makes sense to do so, then sure. However, if the different views in the template are completely unrelated, then it may not make sense. Can you elaborate a bit more on what this website will do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one view, but if it starts to get complex, accounting for each possible input and output can become a headache. I suggest you use as many views as you need and then later implement [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to present everything as if it's only one-page

Comment: But can I keep one template only?

Comment: Technically yes. Just ask yourself if that's all you need. If so, there's no problem. If it starts to get messy you might want to split it up

Answer (score 0):

Seems like if that is the only thing that you want to do, having one FormView and handling the cases accordingly should suffice. For a given form, if it's not necessary, keeping it to one view is generally a good choice.